# Is there a way to disable pip outside of a virtual environment?

Tags: package-management, python, pip

Since asking a question about [Pip vs Package Manager for handling Python Packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/450008/288980) I've
learned a lot, especially about virtual environments with the `venv` module.
These days I almost exclusively install packages with `pip` *inside* virtual
environments. I almost rarely install a system-wide python package.

One thing I'm always terrified of, though, is the possibility that I'll run a
`pip install` command without realizing I don't have a `venv` activated.

## Is there a way to blacklist pip *only* when I'm not in a `venv`?

Comment: There is little chance you'll mess up things anyway (unless you work as root). Outside of venv, `pip install` will require root privileges so you are forced to use `--user` flag and inside the venv, `pip install --user` will fail because the user site is not accessible.

Comment: @hoefling I feel like a moron for not realizing that.

Comment: You shouldn't, it's a good question. You can even uninstall the system pip if your distro supports that, I don't have it installed on my box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly use a shell alias to take over `pip` when outside the venv.

`alias 'pip=cowsay "You are not in a virtual environment"'`

And inside the virtualenv startup file (e.g. the one that gets sourced when you enter the venv):

`unalias 'pip'`

Comment: Or in a different PATH...but yeah, it is one way of dealing with it.

Comment: I've never opened the activate script before. Now that I have, that's a pretty snazzy idea.

Answer (score 11):

There's a global option [`require-virtualenv`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#cmdoption-require-virtualenv) to require a virtual environment when operating `pip`.

Several ways to enable this (*pick one*):

- As configuration option (which has my preference) like this, in e.g. `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` or `/etc/pip.conf`:

  ```ini
  [global]
  require-virtualenv = True
  ```

  You can also run this *command* to modify/create the configuration
  file for you:

  ```
  pip config set global.require-virtualenv True
  ```
- Use the environment variable `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV` and set it to value `true`.
- Directly using the `--require-virtualenv` command line option.

If you would then attempt to install packages outside of a virtualenv, you'll see this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

If you need to override this option temporarily for upgrading pip or installing virtualenv on older Python versions, you can prepend the command with `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false`.

N.B.: This option appears to be missing from the `--help` output and docs as a whole in older pip versions (< 22.0), but it's working just fine for me. Tested with 20.3.4 as latest version on Python 2.7.x.

Sidenote: [PEP 704](https://peps.python.org/pep-0704/) (Draft at the time of writing) is a proposal to *"[...] recommends that package installers like pip require a virtual environment by default on Python 3.13+"*.