# How to install python-reportlab for python 2 on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, python

Since I began using Arch, I have always installed python packages from the Arch repos instead of by using any python package manager (such as `pip`).

Now I am trying to install [ExportPDFCMYK](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ExportPDFCMYK). That depends on `Uniconvertor` and `ImageMagick`. The problem is that `Uniconvertor` depends on the missing package `python2-reportlab`.

This is one of those very rare times when my usual package installation workflow is not going to cut it.

What steps can I use to install `python2-reportlab` on Arch? Can I do it using a python package manager? Will that be sufficient to satisfy the dependencies for `Uniconvertor` package?

Alternatively, is there another method I can use to install [ExportPDFCMYK](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ExportPDFCMYK), which is my end goal anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for installing [`reportlab`](https://pypi.org/project/reportlab/):

1. `pip2 install reportlab`
2. Write a `PKGBUILD` for `python2-reportlab` to generate an Arch package

See [Pip vs Package Manager for handling Python Packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/450008) to decide between the two options. The second option requires you to invest more time but if you push your `PKGBUILD` to the AUR, you support the community. Trust me, it is not that hard.

If you go with the second option, read [Creating packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages), [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD), and then [Python package guidelines](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python_package_guidelines).

Comment: Would `pip install reportlab` give me the python2 or python3 version or reportlab? I need python2 in this case. Also, maybe I'm stupid, but last time I tried to write a `PKGBUILD ` I could not do it.

Comment: It looks like I need `pip2 install reportlab`. Should that be run with or without `sudo`?

Comment: If you only need reportlab for your user, try `pip2 install --user`.

Comment: I need it for all users. So should I run `sudo pip2 install reportlab`?

Comment: Yes. Omitting `sudo` would result in a 'Permission denied' error.